# Android Kotlin Realm Proper Way to Query+Update Async

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I recently faced a problem in which i had in memory a RealResult List of objects and was showing it in a view. Upon user click, the current showing item should be marked as deleted in realm (property `isDeleted`)

So i was just getting that object from the lazy `RealmResults` list, open a transaction and mark it deleted. As the RealmResults are auto-updated, i had a change listener bound to a `notifityDataSetChanged`. Everything works fine except this warning:

```
Mixing asynchronous queries with local writes should be avoided. Realm will convert any async queries to synchronous in order to remain consistent. Use asynchronous writes instead
```

Which is problematic because my list is enormous and i don't want the query to become `sync`. I solved it this way, which i don't know it it is right. Instead of giving the item object to the update function, i give the id of the object, and then do this:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->

            realm.executeTransactionAsync {
                // find the item
                realm.where(ItemRealm::class.java)
                        .equalTo(ItemRealm.ID, itemId).findFirstAsync()
                        .addChangeListener(object : RealmChangeListener<ItemRealm> {
                            override fun onChange(element: ItemRealm) {
                                element.deleted = true
                                element.removeChangeListener(this)
                            }
                        })
            }
        }
```

The problem which im unsure is the `async` part of the query inside an async transaction.

Edit. Actually, it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.`

Edit2: Tried this and show Realm access on different thread:

```
fun setItemDeleted(itemId: Long) {
        // write so new realm instance
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
            realm.executeTransactionAsync {
                // find the item
                val item = realm.where(ItemRealm::class.java)
                        .equalTo(ItemRealm.TIMESTAMP, itemId).findFirst()
                item?.userDeleted = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm mostly surprised it didn't just crash altogether, saying you're trying to add a change listener on a non-looper thread, or that you're accessing a background thread's Realm object from the UI thread.

Comment: ya. realm edit please

Comment: any idea why keep giving access on different thread on edit 2?

Comment: This truly depends on where you're calling `setItemDeleted()` from.

Comment: calling it from main thread

Comment: ....I still think your error is elsewhere. I'd have to see a stack trace to tell for certain.

Comment: the stack trace point to the query line. This solved the problem: Observable.just(item‌​Id) .subscribeOn(Schedul‌​ers.io()) .subscribe { val realm = Realm.getDefaultInst‌​ance() realm.executeTransac‌​tion { realm.where(ItemReal‌​m::class.java).findFi‌​rst().userDeleted = true } }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in `executeTransactionAsync()` runs on a background thread, so you should use the synchronous methods to obtain your object inside it.

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
    realm.executeTransactionAsync { bgRealm ->
        // find the item
        val item = bgRealm.where(ItemRealm::class.java)
                        .equalTo(ItemRealm.ID, itemId).findFirst()
        item?.deleted = true
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. but either way it won't work. Think its because i'm getting a new fresh realm instance in the main threads, and then i'm using it on bg thread. Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Comment: ....that shouldn't be the case with **this** code I wrote, so I think that crash is coming from elsewhere.

Comment: tried this and works:  Observable.just(itemId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe {
                    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                    realm.executeTransaction {
                        realm.where(ItemRealm::class.java).findFirst().userDeleted = true
                    }
                }

Comment: Well you kinda shoulda added the fact you're using RX into the question. But yes, that works.

Comment: i wasn't. but with your solution it gives me that error. I think it's weird too. Can't understand why

Comment: this sounds like the solution. bona try it out :p but i'm also positive thats the reason

Comment: We shouldn't use `executeTransactionAwait`?

Comment: What is `executeTransactionAwait`? Technically I used `executeTransactionAsync` here because I was assuming that UI thread writes have been happening, and the easiest way to do a background thread write with realm is `executeTransactionAsync`. Of course, you can use synchronous write on background thread too.